# Filling Button the Table Cell

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make an html page for my web app using phone gap and I need the table to occupy the whole page, so I used width: 100% and height: 100% to have the table occupy the whole page; however, I want my buttons to fill the whole table cell when I used width: 100% it occupied the whole width and it responds as well when you manipulate with the page size, but when I used height: 100% it does not do anything. On the other hand, when I manipulate the buttons font the height of the button changes. How can I have the buttons and font resize according to window and table size. Here is my HTML and CSS code I am also using twitter-bootstrap. Thank you in advance!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
        <manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    </manifest>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="Description" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Stylesheet Location" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Settings</title>


 </head>
 <body>


    <table class="table table-borderless">
  <tr>
   <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film" id="glyph1" style="vertical-align: middle"></span><br>Broadcast</button></td>
   <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video" id="glyph1" style="vertical-align: middle"></span><br>Video</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music" id="glyph1" style="vertical-align: middle"></span><br>Audio</button></td>
   <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" id="glyph1" style="vertical-align: middle"></span><br>Network</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" id="glyph1" style="vertical-align: middle"></span><br>System</button></td>
   <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" id="glyph1" style="vertical-align: middle"></span><br>Help</button></td>
  </tr>
  </table>


  <script type="text/javascript">
            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
      myWebView.loadUrl("file:///C:/Android/Apps/workshop/www/98001~ue.html");
  </script>

 </body>

    table, td {
    background:  #181812;
    border: 2px solid #333100;
}
body{
    background:  #181812;
}
.btn-default {
    background: #FC0;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    }
tr {
    padding-top: auto;
    padding-bottom: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    padding-left: auto;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Will you fiddle it out

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your css :

```
body,html{height:100%;width:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much! Yes can you please tell us why this works?

Comment: Each browser have a different comportement. The best way to write some css is to fix the default value.

I guess your application which is compiled don't have the same default value for body and html as your browser in your computer.